# Rails form: Let user choose between multiple choice to complete string

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, input

Ok so my users have a profile. On this profile they can choose a background color for their profile. The color is a string. 
<%= @profile.color %> 
In the profile form, they can fill the string with a color or an hexadecimal code, because I have then a variable css using this string for each users.

My question is, How could I let users choose between pre-defined colors, like twitter is doing or vine ? I am not sure how to create such a form.

For example they can choose between six colors and also an input to put an exact hex code.

Can someone put me on track ?

Thanks

```
<div class="form-group">
    Profile color
    <%= f.text_field :color, id: "inputstyle",  class: "form-control", placeholder: "eg: Black or #dde244" %>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to be clearer about what you mean by "choosing between pre-defined colors". Are they defined somewhere, or just hard coded into the view?

Comment: Tbh using color_field is great enough (cc. Dusht answers). What I wanted to accomplished, was to pre-set colors somewhere, then let users choose between these colors for their profile background. An alternative to choosing between these colors was to enter an hex code of the color. It's exactly how you can set up a color for your twitter profile, if you're using twitter: click edit profile and then you'll see on the left than you can choose between pre-filled colors.

Comment: No problem, I upvoted `color_field` because it was new to me :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [color_field](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-color_field) (work only with Rails 4)

Also for text box for inputting hex values, be sure to put regex to validate

`var color_code  = /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test('#ac3')`